# My MFC control buttons in my MFC dialog are not working

Tags: c++, mfc

My `OK` and `Cancel` buttons stopped working after I've added tab dialog to my main dialog.

```
void CFirstMfcProjectDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CDialogEx::OnOK();
}


void CFirstMfcProjectDlg::OnBnClickedCancel()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CDialogEx::OnCancel();
}
```

These are the tabs that I've created:

```
    m_Dialog[0]->Create(m_DialogID[0], this);
    m_Dialog[1]->Create(m_DialogID[1], this);
    m_Dialog[2]->Create(m_DialogID[2], this);
```

Comment: Why are you adding what maybe appears to be message map entries for IDOK and IDCANCEL? There are already virtual functions that you can overreid for OnOK() and OnCancel() that are in the CDialog class.

Comment: Thank you the problem is solved now.